# I got Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5.1" while reading csv

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

```
int numLinesToSkip = 0;
        char delimiter = ',';
        RecordReader recordReader = new CSVRecordReader(numLinesToSkip,delimiter);
//        recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(new File(DownloaderUtility.IRISDATA.Download(),"iris.txt")));
        recordReader.initialize(new FileSplit(
                new File("iris.csv")
        ));
        //Second: the RecordReaderDataSetIterator handles conversion to DataSet objects, ready for use in neural network
        int labelIndex = 4;     //5 values in each row of the iris.txt CSV: 4 input features followed by an integer label (class) index. Labels are the 5th value (index 4) in each row
        int numClasses = 3;     //3 classes (types of iris flowers) in the iris data set. Classes have integer values 0, 1 or 2
        int batchSize = 150;    //Iris data set: 150 examples total. We are loading all of them into one DataSet (not recommended for large data sets)

        DataSetIterator iterator = new RecordReaderDataSetIterator(recordReader,batchSize,labelIndex,numClasses);
        DataSet allData = iterator.next();
```

I want to read my csv, but it says that 5.1, which is first value, is String.

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: If you already solved your problem, please consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't skipping first row of dataset.